# Build takes significant time after registering CustomViewModelFactory

Tags: wpf, mvvm, catel

I'm using amazing catel mvvm framework. But I've faced with issue while registering CustomViewModelFactory:
When I'm adding this code in App.xaml.cs, building becomes slow (1 min).

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType<IViewModelFactory, DbViewerViewModelFactory>();
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
```

Can I reduce this time?

Update: I've compared outputs and found that output is almost equaly (in terms of containted .exe and dll) difference is in order and in entries like this:
    The thread '' (0x1e68) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

slow build output:

```
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\DBViewer.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1c54) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x34) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\DBViewer.exe', Symbols loaded.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DBViewer.App.App'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DBViewer.App.InitializeComponent'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\FirstFloor.ModernUI.dll', Symbols loaded.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\Catel.Core.dll', Symbols loaded.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\Catel.MVVM.dll', Symbols loaded.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationCore.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.resources.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.resources.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x115c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

fast build output

```
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\DBViewer.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1c7c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b84) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1948) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x1f60) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\DBViewer.exe', Symbols loaded.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DBViewer.App.App'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DBViewer.App.InitializeComponent'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\FirstFloor.ModernUI.dll', Symbols loaded.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\Catel.MVVM.dll', Symbols loaded.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\declspec\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DBViewer\DBViewer\binary\Catel.Core.dll', Symbols loaded.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationCore.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.resources.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.resources.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DBViewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Comment: You could have a look at the building log and compare a build with and without these lines. That way you can determine what is taking the extra time. Do not forget to time the release builds as well.

Comment: It might be because when you don't use any code from an assembly, it does not actually include these references. If this is the first reference to anything inside Catel, that might cause a minor increase (but not 1 minute). Are you doing custom post-build steps such as merging assemblies or obfuscating?

Comment: I'm not do post-build steps such as merging assemblies or obfuscating.

Comment: Are you sure it's the build that is slow? Or is it debugging that is slow?

Comment: Sure. Because I've puted breakpoint on `ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType<IViewModelFactory, DbViewerViewModelFactory>();` string. And even some outputs entries comes slow.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducable scenario here:

https://catelproject.atlassian.net/